Does a character holding one or two non-weapons or improvised weapons with the unarmed fighting style qualify for the d8 unarmed strike damage die?
The text for the Fighting Style Option "Unarmed Fighting" says (emphasis mine):

Your unarmed strikes can deal bludgeoning damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier on a hit. If you aren't wielding any weapons or a shield when you make the attack roll, the d6 becomes a d8. [...]

If a Fighter with the Tavern Brawler Feat and Unarmed Fighting style is holding a flask of acid, oil, or alchemist's fire, etc. in one hand and a torch, rock, or goblin, etc. in the other and using them as improvised weapons, would any unarmed strikes they made be a d6 or a d8?
The Tavern Brawler's proficiency with improvised weapons probably would not affect the answer to this question but I included it for completeness.
Note I am NOT talking about applying unarmed strike damage to improvised weapons. The question is specifically asking if improvised weapons (basically any item) in hand count as weapons for the fighting style.

Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you are new to SE websites! Happy gaming!

If such objects are used as improvised weapons, or with the intent to use them as improvised weapons, then the damage will be d6.
An improvised weapon is... well, a weapon, as the name suggests.
In the descripted scenario, in one hand the character has something (rock, dead goblin) that will be used as an improvised weapon: hence, the requirements are not met.
If none of the wielded objects are used or will be used as improvised weapons, then a head butt or a kick will qualify for the d8 damage.
Timing
Since the rules are not crystal clear, there are some edge cases a DM has to consider.
For example, a character with Action Surge and Unarmed Fighting holds a vial of acid in one hand and decides to punch an enemy: they deal d8+mod damage, due to the Fighting Style. Then, they decide to use Action Surge and throw the vial of acid. In this case, the DM should make a call:

allow the second attack, with no consequences
allow the second attack, but backtracking the unarmed strike, making the player reroll for the damage, using a d6 instead of a d8.


Or the third and best option, disallow the wielding of a weapon after the d8 is taken

@DaleM Yep, I thought about it, but I did not put as an option. Indeed, one can use the second attack with another unarmed strike, but the fact is that using the unarmed strike does not prevent to make another attack..

Minor detail, but I believe throwing a vial of acid after making a punch would not work with extra attack RAW as you use the Use an Object action to attack with it, not the attack action. Could still be done with action surge.
More relevant, this answer seems to contradict the accepted answer to this question which while not damning per say, is worth noting.

Actually on further inspection it wouldn't be contradictory if improvised weapons count as weapons but not melee weapons. Frankly I'm not sure about that either way.

@Pvt.Joker You're right about the action economy, I overlooked it: I 'll correct the answer. For the second part, I fail to see the contradiction.

Potentially yes, but the timing requires a ruling
Unarmed Fighting Style says:

Your unarmed strikes can deal bludgeoning damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier on a hit. If you aren't wielding any weapons or a shield when you make the attack roll, the d6 becomes a d8. [...]

This upgrade to a d8 occurs "when you make the attack roll".  Thus, your question becomes 'at the moment I make my unarmed strike, am I wielding a weapon?' and thus unable to claim the damage upgrade?
This is actually a complicated question and requires several steps to resolve.  Feel free to 'jump ahead' to the part(s) in which you have doubts:
(1) Can I make unarmed strikes if I have items in hand?
(2) Are improvised weapons actually weapons?
(3) If so, when are improvised weapons, weapons?
(4) Is an unarmed strike made at the same time that an improvised weapon is a weapon?
Can I make unarmed strikes if I have items in hand?
It is certainly permissible RAW for you to have weapons (including improvised weapons), in both hands and still be making unarmed strikes.  As the PHB says about unarmed strikes:

Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons).

Since unarmed strikes aren't necessarily made with your hands, you can hold items, including weapons, in your hands while making unarmed strikes1.
Are improvised weapons actually weapons?
If I have a torch in one hand and a dead goblin in the other, am I wielding weapons?
That is easily answered by the rules on improvised weapons (emphases mine):

Often, an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such. For example, a table leg is akin to a club.

These rules continue, describing when an improvised weapon can use a weapon proficiency bonus and when an improvised weapon does weapon-type damage - but those are examples of how an improvised weapon can count as a weapon.  The rules make it clear that while an improvised weapon is not a weapon in an existential sense, it can be treated as one in a functional sense2.  Thus, for the purpose of other rules that interact with weapons, improvised weapons will count as weapons.
When is an improvised weapon a weapon?
Are all the dead goblins in the world weapons all the time, or do they become weapons only when someone picks them up with the intent to use in a fight?  Or only when they are actively swung rather than carried?  The timing matters, since they interfere with Unarmed Fighting Style only at the precise moment of your unarmed strike attack roll.
RAW we don't have guidance beyond the passage quoted above, that an improvised weapon is "often" similar to a weapon and that when it is similar, it "can be treated as such".  It is up to your DM to determine what this means, or even in what sense it is 'similar'.
I think the most reasonable interpretation is that 'unarmed fighting is most effective when you have your hands free and your movements are not restricted by having to avoid hitting yourself with your own weapon; is your improvised weapon something that would hinder your unarmed attacks in the way that a dedicated weapon would?'
RAI, a tweet from Jeremy Crawford3 provides some perspective:

An improvised weapon is, indeed, a weapon, but only the moment it's used as such. A chair/shield/etc isn't a weapon otherwise.

If your DM accepts this unofficial guidance, then the items in hand would count as weapons, and thus 'spoil' the damage upgrade of Unarmed Fighting Style, but only at the "moment" they are used as weapons, since outside this moment they would not count.  This still leaves some latitude for DM interpretation of what a "moment" is, though.
Is an unarmed strike made at the same time that an improvised weapon is a weapon?
The timing of the damage upgrade from Unarmed Fighting Style is very precise: "If you aren't wielding any weapons or a shield when you make the attack roll..."  The timing of an improvised weapon counting as a wielded weapon, on the other hand, is more vague.
A generous DM using the JC tweet as RAI might interpret "moment" to mean the exact moment of the improvised weapon attack itself, which is not likely to be simultaneous with your unarmed strike.  Thus you could use your Unarmed Fighting Style damage upgrade because at the precise moment of your head-butt the goblin was just a dead goblin, and not a weapon as it had been a second before or after.
A less generous DM working from RAW might not agree, and might rule that improvised weapons are "similar" to actual weapons any time you carry them, because they would similarly interfere with your unarmed strikes.  (Counterpoint; the Unarmed Fighting Style could easily have mentioned as a prerequisite that you need a "free hand" as you do in grappling and some cases of spellcasting, but did not).
Given the 'simultaneous nature' of a combat round, I personally would be inclined to disallow Unarmed Fighting Style during any round in which the improvised weapons had been used as weapons.  For example, if your fighter had used a torch held in hand to make an opportunity attack on the turn previous to their own, then on their own turn I would rule that they could not use Unarmed Fighting Style because they were still wielding a weapon.  On the other hand, if they had been carrying a dead goblin since the start of the fight but had not yet made an attack with it, I would allow their kicks to have the Unarmed Fighting Style bonus to damage.
Finally, the inclusion of the Tavern Brawler Feat does not affect any of these conclusions.  It does beg the question of which damage-replacement rule, Tavern Brawler or Unarmed Fighting Style, takes precedence - but that is a separate question.

1As a DM, I would want a player to have some sort of narrative justification for why their character is running around with their hands full while head-butting opponents, and why that would not result in some sort of penalty on their attacks, but what you are proposing works fine RAW.
2 Further reading at: Are Improvised Weapons used in melee actually melee weapons?
3 There are different schools of thought on Crawford's unofficial tweets.  I tend to ignore them when they are unrelated or contradictory to clear RAW.  In cases such as this, when RAW is unclear, I think they can be helpful in understanding RAI.

I think a pretty good answer.  Not sure why the downvotes.

@Jack Kinda scratching my head on that one, too.  I don't think I say anything too different from Eddymage, and it came in a bit before his.  Some people auto-downvote for including JC tweets.  ::Shrug::  Once an answer gets to -3 and is hidden it is hard to recover because few people are going to look at it - I appreciate that you did.

@Jack Imho, this answer is too long and convoluted: it contains a lot of related but unnecessary material and it takes a while before getting to the point. For me, this kind of answers are not helpful., hence my DV. About the JC's tweets, I think that sometimes may provide some insights, even if JC contradicted himself several times.

Good answer, going that much in depth is not a fault in my opinion. Even from a narrative standpoint, there is a big difference between carrying and wielding a potential "weapon". So it makes sense to distinguish between the two right from the start.

Yes, we are actually saying the same, but I must admit that I find your answer (and, honestly, most of your answers) unnecessarly long, with long commentary that are tangently related to the topic and sentences that may benefit from some shortening. That's just my impression, I do not think that you should change anything, we have just different styles: I agree that some users prefer to write and have really short answers (I am casting Invoke @DaleM here!), some others prefer ones direct to the point, some prefer deep essays.

Just an example, I take for granted that improvised weapons are weapons because it is in their name, there is little to discuss about it: as we both observe, they are weapons when they are used as weapons or when the intent is to use them as weapons. Menacing swirling a piece of wood with a killing gaze is different than pick it up and pass it hand to hand to a creature.

@Eddymage  That's a fair characterization of the difference between our answers in general, and I'm glad the site supports both.  For this question in particular, I don't think "it's in the name" is sufficient.  An improvised weapon that I use in melee is not a melee weapon, although it is a weapon.  You yourself argue that a dead creature is not a creature.  The spell chill touch is not a touch spell and doesn't do cold damage.  Assuming information from a name is not a given in 5e.

An improvised weapon is not a melee nor a ranged weapon because it is not listed or characterized in the proper list. We already discussed about dead creatures, and Chill Touch actually creates a skeletal hand that touches the target, and the description says that it "[...] assail(s) it with the chill of the grave", which is not simple cold. But we can create a huge thread on how poorly the 5th edition is worded...

I came up with something that may counterargument my stance: is a Dragonborn Breath Weapon a weapon??? Per my reasoning, yes, but I am actually dubious..

@Eddymage That a dragon-like creature has a "breath weapon attack" goes at least back to first edition, and possibly farther.  I think that is legacy phrasing and we really can't expect it to meet a 5e definition of "is this a weapon" or "is this an attack"?

I think that is stated that is not an attack, but I am wondering if it could be considered a weapon (see my -possibly wrong- answer to Can a dragonborn use his breath weapon as a weapon attack if he is hasted?).

@Eddymage I just did a skim of SAC.  Have a look at the answers surrounding Pact of the Blade.  I think the idea is that 'anything listed on the PHB weapons table is assumed to be a weapon'; otherwise, it is only a weapon if the text specifically says it is a weapon, and the 'name' of the feature doesn't count.  For example "The game often makes exceptions to general rules, and this is an important exception: that unarmed strikes count as melee weapon attacks despite not being weapons." vs the spell spiritual weapon which makes spell attacks, not weapon attacks.

Yeah, at least Warlock's feature specifies that you have to choose the weapon among the melee ones in the table of PHB. Yeah, there are object that are listed as "objects" but are actually weapons per description(see the Siege Equipment section in the DMG, for example). But I am still unsure by not considering a weapon a thing that is named "weapon". I have to still think about it.
